# Java android bitmap = null for certain images

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, null

I' making an android app which allows the user to take a photo and then the app will print some RGB value etc. I'm saving the pictures taken on the phone and then I make a bitmap out of those png files. I just found out that I should sleep the application for a moment in order for the image to be saved. But I'm still getting that the bitmap is null for some images I take. If I take an image of Rubik's cube with it's 6 different colors I almost never get the null pointer exception. But if I take a picture of the wall or something else the bitmap is = null.

Does anyone know what I should do in order to fix this?

```
Bitmap myBitmap;
final String dir =  
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + 
"/picFolder/";
try{
    file = dir+Integer.toString(side)+".jpg";
    File f = new File(file);
    options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file,options);

    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
            cube[side-1][i][j] = getColor(myBitmap, i, j);
        }
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("er0r", "HERE:::: " + e.toString());

}
```

Comment: Please post some code. What does "I am saving the pictures taken on the phone" mean? Are YOU in control of the camera? There is an intent for this which will return the image.

Comment: I added the code now. The application opens the camera and allows the user to take a photo and save it on the phone. Then the application attempts to make a bitmap out of the photo, but sometimes it is null.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  How do you know myBitmap is null?

Comment: change, `Log.e("er0r", "HERE:::: " + e.toString());` to `Log.e("er0r", "HERE:::: " + e.toString(), e);` and then recreate the problem and add the stacktrace from logcat to your question

Comment: Well, in documentation `inJustDecodeBounds - If set to true, the decoder will return null (no bitmap), but the out...`

Comment: decodeFile() returns null if the bitmap would become to big for available memory. With the options parameter you can scale it down to a smaller resolution And get the colors of the smaller one. You will not get the colors of the original image as that bitmap is null.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem when I was developing camera in my app.
For some images it was working fine and for some images it was showing null.
Later I found that is a size issue.
I fixed that issue like this,

```
private static Bitmap compressBitmap(Bitmap original) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
        return decoded;
    }
```

Let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: Thanks, it almost worked :P
It works more often now I believe, but still, when I take a picture of the wall or someting i get this exception:
HERE:::: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference.

Comment: By the way, here is how I applied your code:
"
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file,options);
            myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
"

Comment: `please accept my answer and upvote it. ` ?? Your answer is completely wrong. It does not handle a null bitmap from decodeFile(). I wonder why OP marked this nonsense as correct. I hope he will undo it. And vote it down.

Comment: True, his answer did not help. I fixed it myself. The problem was that I was trying to create a bitmap from the image before it was finished saving the image.